# Javascript SRC is not working in IPhone Safari and Android

Tags: javascript, android, dhtml, mobile-safari

As per the requirement i need to change the image src dynamically, hence i using JavaScript to accomplish this.

I am accessing the image with id and adding new src depending on the user click, below is the code where i am getting the problem. Through out the process i am getting the updated SRC Data of image, but its looks strange that i could see updated image in desktop browser but not in Mobile safari and Andriod.

Please help

```
//This is id for fetching the user data
var text_food=document.getElementById("plateText_food");

//User Data
var currentFoodName=text_food.innerHTML; 

//as per the requirement removing space and adding "-"
var regExp = /\s+/g;
var foodName=currentFoodName.replace(regExp,'-');

//Detail URL
var detailURL_food01 = 'img/beer_images_png/' + foodName + '.png';

//id FOR ACCESSING IMAGE 
var updateFoodImage=document.getElementById("detailURL_food");

//adding updated src
updateFoodImage.src = detailURL_food01;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *should* work, provided it's run at the right time.  Both the browsers you're having issues when render and load content much slower...nature of working on mobile, that means you need to be *sure* that your code runs after the DOM is loaded, on `window.onload` for example, otherwise when you execute `document.getElementById("plateText_food")`...that `id="plateText_food"` element may not be in the DOM ready to find yet.

Try a simple `alert()` to test this, at the end (you won't get the alert if it errors before, another indicator):

```
alert(detailURL_food01);
updateFoodImage.src = detailURL_food01;
```

Comment: I am loading content on window onload, i tested the